# How to transfer data from CSV to Excel using Beanshell in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I want to save CSV file data into Excel file which is passed in parameterization using Beanshell. If it is possible than please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, it just the matter of time and efforts. If I'm getting your question right and you need to convert CSV file into Excel file, you can do it via [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/):

1. Download [tika-app-xxx.jar](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) and save it into "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Using [Apache POI Spreadsheet](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) API you can read and write Excel files, see following reference guides for examples

   - [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)
   - [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)